# change size or resolution of screen with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, screen, screen-resolution

can we change size of screen of browser with  jquery or something else that affect CSS media screen?

i want to test my responsive site with default resolutions. i have to change windows screen resolution now.

how do http://groundwork.sidereel.com/?url=home change size of screen? -please look at top of front page.

Comment: Go to Dev tools in chrome, click on the gear icon in the right hand bottom of the screen, change the useragent and resolution. Or simply resize your browser. You don't need jquery for this.

Comment: thnk u. but how do http://groundwork.sidereel.com/?url=home change size of screen? -please look at top of front page.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with changing the screen size.

You can set size in CSS or JS. So: "when the document has a width/height of x do a, etc"

It looks like it changes the resolution, but it doesn't.

Check out CSS viewports